# Socket send() followed by read() immediately getting junk

Tags: c++, sockets

Coding in c++ on a linux RHEL7 machine.
I have a client-server that are sending back and forth fairly large messages (it needs to handle 10MB). In order to read these large messages properly, I set up a two-message system where first the size of the message is sent, followed by the actual message. This way the receiver knows to keep reading until the message is complete. Both client and server are using the same library functions for their read and send.

The issue I'm having with the code below is that each time I go through the send_with_length() function, the next read_with_length() call is immediately grabbing a few bytes of junk from the socket buffer before the receiver has a chance to respond. Since it tries to interpret this junk as an integer corresponding to a message length, it tries to create a ridiculously large buffer and crashes.

I have an ugly-as-hell workaround, in which the receiver immediately sends a "sacrificial" message back, and the sender reads this message along with the junk (the message gets garbled and cut off) before proceeding to the actual read_with_length() call. But I need to figure out why it seems that the send call is leaving junk behind that gets interpreted as a new message by the read.

P.S. I expect someone will come along and suggest a very helpful open source library that fixes all my problems. But due to constraints of the project, assume that they are not allowed.

```
int ReadXBytes(int socket, int x, void* buffer)
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int result;
    while (bytesRead < x)
    {
        result = read(socket, (char*)buffer+bytesRead, x - bytesRead);
        if (result < 1 )
        {
            return 0;
        }
        bytesRead += result;
    }
    return bytesRead;
    return 0;
}

int send_with_length(int sock, string message, string* err){
    int messageLength = message.length();
    if (send(sock, (void*)&messageLength, sizeof(messageLength), 0) < 0) {
        *err = "Send Length Error: ";
        *err += string(strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }

    if (send(sock, message.c_str(), messageLength, 0) < 0) {
        *err = "Send Message Error: ";
        *err += string(strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int read_with_length(int sock, string* message, string* err){
    *message = "";
    int messageLength =0;
    
    if(ReadXBytes(sock, sizeof(messageLength), (void*)(&messageLength))){
        char buffer[messageLength];
        int bytesRead = ReadXBytes(sock, messageLength, (void*)buffer);
        if(bytesRead > 0){
            *message = string(buffer);
            return bytesRead;
        }

        *err = "Read Error: " + string(strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `char buffer[messageLength];` is not valid C++, although some compilers (not mine) have VLA as an extension.  Instead use `std::vector<char> buffer(messageLength);`.  Putting a 10MB array on the stack may be part of your problem, too.

Comment: "void* buffer" , "   "return bytesRead" followed by "return 0;" ... ?

Comment: you have logic on read side if not whole buffer received in one shot, but you do not have it on send side, that could be the issue.

Comment: "I expect someone will come along and suggest a very helpful open source library that fixes" btw such questions are offtopic on SO.

Comment: I'm testing this with much smaller messages (a hundred bytes or so) than what I need to handle eventually, so it's not currently an issue with size that's causing it.

Comment: Are the sockets blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: Blocking. The client has a 5 second timeout set, but it's not running into that.

Comment: Again `send()` is not guaranteed to send all your data in one shot, you need `SendXBytes()` as well

Comment: I'll look into that and implement that for safety's sake. Though currently in my tests the send() is sending everything in one shot, so seems not to be the root cause of the current issue.

Comment: What is "junk from the socket buffer"? `read` *never* returns "junk from the socket buffer". If you're getting "junk from the socket buffer", it's not `read` that is doing it.

Comment: @Eljay FWIW, this is a compiler-specific extension, and on compilers that support it, it does exactly what you'd expect it to

Comment: `string(buffer);` constructs the string incorrectly, because buffer is not `'\0'` terminated and may itself contain embedded `'\0'` characters.  It should be `string(buffer, buffer+messageLength);`

Comment: @Eljay good catch, I bet that the reason. On send side `std::string::length()` is used which does not include `\0` terminator. Also it can be `string(buffer, messageLength)`

Comment: On a side note, `ReadXBytes()` is not handling the case when `read()` returns 0 if the peer disconnects gracefully in the middle of reading.

Comment: @Eljay Still unsure of how this caused the issue I was seeing, but changing to string(buffer, messageLength) fixed it. Thanks!